Firebase Next.js with SSR - firebase.json rewrites config
I am trying to get Next.js v14 running on Firebase with SSR / getserversideprops
I am unable to use #npm export as this only allows for static not SSR builds
The #npm run build folder is the default .next
I have setup the neccessary server side firebase functions in functions\src\index.ts
    const nextApp = next({dev: false, conf: {distDir: ".next"}});
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

exports.ssrFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return nextApp.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res));
});

and provided the corect permissions in Google Cloud. After this function was setup the 404 became "Internal Server Errror" (ref Firebase cloud function "Your client does not have permission to get URL /200 from this server").
If I now go to https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/server/pages/ I can see my homepage in the uploaded .next/server/pages/index.html but not rendered
my firebase.json
    {
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "runtime": "nodejs20",
    "source": "functions",
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log",
      "*.local"
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": ".next",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      ".firebase/**",
      ".firebaserc"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/(.*)",
        "destination": "/$1",
        "function": "ssrFunction"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "extensions": {}
}

my next.config.mjs
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
export default {
    rewrites: async () => [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: "/server/pages/api/:path*",
      },
    ],
  };

